# Content div not filling up the remaining space

Tags: html, css, height

Basically #content is not obeying the height: auto attribute.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title id="title" runat="server">AMIDS: Advanced Management Information Data Store</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container
        {
            background-color: White;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 600px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #header
        {
            height: 50px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #headerLeft
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/HeaderLeft.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 50px;
            width: 5px;
        }
        #headerCenter
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/HeaderCenter.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 50px;
            width: 99.2%;
        }
        #headerRight
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/HeaderRight.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 50px;
            width: 5px;
        }
        #menu
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/Menu.jpg');
            height: 20px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #content
        {
            background-color: Pink;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #footer
        {
            height: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #footerLeft
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/FooterLeft.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            width: 5px;
        }
        #footerCenter
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/FooterCenter.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            width: 99.2%;
        }
        #footerRight
        {
            background-image: url('/Amids/App_Themes/Default/Images/FooterRight.jpg');
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            width: 5px;
        }
        * html #container
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
        *
        {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
        }
        html, body, form
        {
         border: none;
         height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerLeft"></div>
            <div id="headerCenter"></div>
            <div id="headerRight"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footerLeft"></div>
            <div id="footerCenter"></div>
            <div id="footerRight"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto is already the default value.
Block level elements don't stretch to fill the parent's height.
So, that div is not supposed to stretch - is it? (Maybe see [height calculation for block level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#normal-block) )
Which would mean is **is** obeying the `height:auto` attribute.

Maybe you can do what you want using `position: absolute; bottom: 10px;` on the footer and some bottom-margin on the content.
Background might be tricky - maybe you can give "pink" background to all body, and white to the header and menu.